# Get images to show at their normal size

Tags: xml, image, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am an XSL-FO newbie. When I render my simple script to pdf using OxygenXML/
XMLmind it automatically resizes my images to their correct size. I have taken the fo output from OxygenXML/
XMLmind and tried to copy it exactly, but the images in my pdf still come out larger than they should be.

What am I doing wrong.
PS: I am using Apache Fop 2.6 to process my .fo files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in" master-name="BodyPage">
            <fo:region-body margin-top=".5in" margin-right=".5in" margin-bottom=".5in" margin-left=".5in"/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="header" extent=".5in" display-align="after"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="footer" extent=".5in" display-align="before"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="BodyPage">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block space-before="1pc">
                <fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image11.png)" content-width="316px" content-height="292px" width="auto" scaling="uniform"/>
                <!-- <fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image11.png)" overflow="hidden" content-width="316px" content-height="292px" width="auto" scaling="uniform"/> -->
            </fo:block>
            
            <fo:block space-before="1pc">
                <fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image11.png)" content-width="316px" content-height="292px" width="auto" height="auto"/>
            </fo:block>
            
            <fo:block space-before="1pc">
                <fo:external-graphic src="url(images/image11.png)" content-width="scale-to-fit" content-height="100%" width="100%" height="auto" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: When you say you render the PDF using the XSL FO from oXygen, what exactly are you doing? Are you using a local copy of FOP that is different that the version that comes with their product? If you are unsure, check the PDF properties of yours and the one from oXygen and see if the version of FOP matches.

Comment: @KevinBrown: In the pdf transformation options, the 2nd tab has an option that instructs Oxygen not to process fo. So instead of outputting a pdf it gives you an fo file. I took that file and processed it using Apache fop for myself.

Comment: And the question again was are you using a different version of FOP than oXygen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your PNG image records its resolution as 72 dots per inch. It is likely, also, that FOP is using 1px as 1/72 inch or 1/96 inch. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#pixels

`content-width="100%"` says to render the image at its intrinsic width, which looks like it will be 316 pixels at, say, 72 pixels per inch or approximately 4.39 inch. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#content-width)

You could:

- Edit the graphic in an image editor to change its resolution
- Edit the graphic to resize it to be a different number of pixels
- Specify a fixed `scale` on the `fo:external-graphic`
- Maybe change FOP's definition of a pixel. AH Formatter has a setting for this (https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-optset.html#pxpi), so FOP might as well

Comment: You were right. It expects 96ppi images and will deform any images it gets to meet this. Haven't found a way to switch this to 72 ppi, but I intend to resize my images(which were 72 ppi). Thanks!